TikZ download suggestion for a complete noob
Hello—I'm a complete novice in the world of LaTex. I'm learning through TexShop and documentation. At this point, I have encountered the need to create graphs and images. The book I'm reading recommends TikZ, but I do not know what that is. Is it a single app? Is it a format? Is it a language? Where can I download TikZ for Mac OSX? I did a Google search, and I'm overwhelmed by the return. It would be a big help if I knew what I was looking for.
I have looked at Overleaf, but there are no downloads available. At least nothing that I can see. Perhaps I missed something.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Welcome! You don't download Overleaf. You use it online. If you do that, just create an account and you can create and compile documents using the online editor. If you want to install locally, install MacTeX. This will automatically include TikZ.

Someone will probably give a longer answer, but for now, there's nothing to download. TikZ is included in TeXShop. It is also included in Overleaf. You only need to include the code \usepackage{tikz} before \begin{document}. The TikZ manual is very long and can be intimidating. If you're using overleaf the TikZ tutorial there is pretty good. In the Overleaf help menu, choose "documentation". Then on the far left, scroll down to "Figures and Tables" and select "TikZ package".

Tikz is a package. Since you use TeXshop, it should be already include in your computer.  You call it with \usepackage{tikz} in the preambule. Here, you can find the tikz manual. It is well written with a lot of examples.

Great! Thank you, everyone! This has been most helpful.

See also How to find the documentation for a package?

To make technically correct some previous: TikZ is not part of TeXShop. Rather TikZ ia LaTeX package that comes as part of the MacTeX system, which includes the TeXShop front end/editor and the TeXLive distribution of TeX itself (and the TeX distribution includes LaTeX).

Welcome. // I suggest reading and trying the tutorials in the pgfmanul first, probably several times over time ;-) Find the manual here together with a shorter intro https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf or online here: https://tikz.dev/ . The basic ideas are simple, but may be hard to grasp in the beginning. // For examples have a look here: https://texample.net/tikz/examples/ , and of course on this site. Click e.g. on the tag you set https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-pgf and review some questions, you feel you might understand. // Doing Tikz is learning Tikz ;-)
